# removing common prefix or suffix

Tags: sas

I have a data set contains a series variables named; `PG_86xt, AG_86xt,...` with same suffix `_86xt`. How can I remove such suffix while renaming these variables?

I know how to [add prefix or suffix](http://support.sas.com/kb/48/674.html). But the logic of removing them seems to be a little bit different. I think `proc dataset modify` is still the way to go. But the length of substring before suffix (or after prefix) is unknown.

#### The example on how to add prefix or suffix

```
data one;
input id name :$10. age score1 score2 score3;
datalines;
1 George 10 85 90 89
2 Mary 11 99 98 91
3 John 12 100 100 100
4 Susan 11 78 89 100
;
run;

proc datasets library = work nolist;
modify one;
rename &suffixlist;
quit;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `scan` function to get the desired result.

By altering the example you have in the link to fit your example:

```
data one;
input id name :$10. age PG_86xt AG_86xt IG_86xt;
datalines;
1 George 10 85 90 89
2 Mary 11 99 98 91
3 John 12 100 100 100
4 Susan 11 78 89 100
;
run;
```

By filtering on only those column that fits your convention (`XX_86xt`), you could use the first part of the scan for renaming.

```
proc sql noprint;
select cats(name,'=',scan(name, 1, '_'))
into :suffixlist
separated by ' '
from dictionary.columns
where libname = 'WORK' and memname = 'ONE' and '86xt' = scan(name, 2, '_');
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `index` function to find the (first) place in each variable name where the suffix / prefix starts, then use that to construct appropriate parameters for `substr`. It's a bit more work than the code in your example, but you'll get there.